# Parametric plot of involute not pretty on rotation

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

```
rb = 1; r[si_] = rb Sec[si]; th[si_] = Tan[si] - si;
ParametricPlot[r[si] {Cos[th[si]], Sin[th[si]]}, {si, 0, 1.5}]
ParametricPlot[
 r[si] {Cos[th[si] + v], Sin[th[si] + v]}, {si, 0, 1.5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> {20, 8}]
```

Not clear why an attempt to rotate the involute curve gets clumsy.Thanks for any workaround solution.

Comment: Use `PlotPoints -> 100` or whatever number gives what you consider satisfactory.

Comment: Lines of rotation by  parameter $v$ do not show at all, but a disk for the full  plot range.